# Volley library not working while posting the data to MVC Web Api

Tags: android, http, post, android-volley

I am trying to POST data to an MVC WebApi using "Volley Library".

You can find the api details here:
http://mzrokz.somee.com/Help/Api/POST-api-LeadNowAppToCore-AddCustomer_firstname

It will return "1" if success. But right now when i am trying to post it returns this exception

```
BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404.
```

This is what I have tried uptill now.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(LeadNowAddUser.this);
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,"http://mzrokz.somee.com/api/LeadNowAppToCore/AddCustomer", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                Log.e("response",response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("firstName","ankur");

                return params;
            }


        };

        queue.add(sr);
```

Please help me. Thanx in Advance.

Comment: You are trying to add custqomer without sending parameters?you are doing bad, you hacer to override getBody inside of gerParams()

Comment: @MaxPinto: 404 resp code is NOT FOUND, not BAD REQUEST :)

Comment: Depends on Server and api, but you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try post data in extension Advanced Rest client of chorme Browser but it error 404.
Please check your webservice

http://i.imgur.com/z70z4km.png

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation in your link, this is the POST request with no body parameter. It uses URL parameter, so you only need to update the URL in your app and remove `getParams`, please see the following screenshot (I use [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)). Hope this helps!

[image: BNK's screenshot]